# How do I alter the output of a field using a views handler

Tags: entities, views

Currently I'm uning [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) to reformat some fields in a view. in the documentation of views it says

> While this module allows you to directly use PHP inside views which may be useful for quick and easy solutions, it is highly advisable to use regular handlers and plugins when available (or even to create one yourself).

In my particular use case, I'm trying to re-format the output of a field that is being loaded by relationship. How would I create a views handler, or a views plugin that does this?

Comment: Have you considered theming the field?

Comment: well thats the trick, I'm trying to output the field to services (in my case the field is a file). Unfortunately, the field is displayed with all of it html markup. Theming does not effect services output

Answer (score 2):

You add your custom views handler using `hook_views_data()` like so:

```
function mymodule_views_data() {
  $data = array(
    ['my_table_name'] => array(
      'my_field_alias' => array(
        'real field' => 'my_field_id',
        'group' => t('Testing'),
        'title' => t('Testing'),
        'help' => t('Testing a thing.'),
        'field' => array(
          'handler' => 'my_custom_views_handler_test',
          'click sortable' => TRUE,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
        ),
        'filter' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
        ),
        'argument' => array(
          'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_string',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

return $data;
}
```

And then you declare your custom views handler:

```
class my_custom_views_handler_test extends views_handler_field {
  /**
   * Render some stuff.
   *
   * Data should be made XSS safe prior to calling this function.
   */
  function render($values) {
    $value = $this->get_value($values);
    return $this->sanitize_value($value);
  }
}
```

Almost all changes you'll be wanting to make should be made in an override of the render function.

Comment: hook_views_data() needs to return $data for it to work.

Comment: right you are. edited.