# Views on custom data source

Tags: 7, views, database

I have an app that has a front end in tons of custom AJAX and fancy JS controls.

These controls all pull from URL which return JSON in a specific format.

I would like to remove all the selection code from the existing system and integrate with drupal:

1. Can views be linked to tables which are not directly managed by Drupal?
2. Can Views have their output overridden to support JSON instead of HTML?

I have googled and found a few projects but none seem to be very active -- I am using D7 maybe D8 for this project :)

Any pointers, hook suggestions, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using [`hook_views_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) to declare your custom tables/fields, use a [custom Views handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/83250/7256) to override or reformat the output.

Comment: This might be useful too: http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/building-views-query-plugins-part-2

Answer (score 2):

Answers:

> Can views be linked to tables which are not directly managed by Drupal?

This is done by the data module - [here is a heads up](http://www.up2technology.com/blog/drupal-7-data-module/).

> Can Views have their output overridden to support JSON instead of HTML?

Install the [views datasource](https://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) project, then enable the views_json module. This outputs the view fields as JSON. You set the output format to JSON, configure it, and all fields are outputted as JSON:

[image: Views Datasources JSON settings]

Take care to uncheck views api  mode if you simply want a JSON file.

Add a path to the new 'page'-type display, and you will see the JSON output.

For me it was somewhat limited, since I you can't change the field names (only hide them). Maybe you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Module [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) can be used to query (not update) any MySQL database table. And Forena can be used as a views style. So the combination of these 2 Forena features should perfectly address the 1st part of the question.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The newest 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Here are some variations of the **mysql database** part in the question:

1. Using a **SQLite** instead of MySQL database: the Forena samples actually get shipped including a (Tiny) SQLite database. Go check it out in the [demo site](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/samples): the data shown there are data contained in the sampledb, which is in SQLite format.
2. Forena comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

Enough reasons for considering giving Forena a try? While doing so, use it's issue queue for any type of support/docu requests you may have.

Be aware: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.